# Website rendering in ie7 mode, but the browser looks like it's ie8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

[image]
A client of mine just sent in a screenshot that one of his staff members took, with the formatting of their website totally broken.

If he were in IE7 I'd understand, but it looks like the screenshot was sent was of an iE9+ browser.

Anyone know what might be going on? it doesn't look like the compatibility mode is clicked in, shouldn't CSS3 be rendering correctly on this browser?

Answer (score -1):

Screenshot looks like IE8.   You can reference this site for CSS compatibility: http://caniuse.com/

For CSS3 compatibility with IE7 or IE8, you can use a JS to 'mimic' some properties.   More information here: https://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/